# How to adjust frame of custom keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, custom-keyboard

I am using custom keyboard LNNumberpad in my application.
I am use it as an input view for UItextField . My application is for iPad .
In my application I am adding two view side by side on screen.
In one of the view I have UITextField .. for that UITextField I have sets inutView as LNNumberpad keyboard.

When I am selecting that UITextField LNNumberpad is appear. But what I want is I need to display that keyboard frame to UITextField superview frame.

As screen has two views side by side.
I mean I want keyboard will appear only for second view on screen.

[image: Please refer attached Image I want keyboard to appear just below enter quantity here textField]

Comment: Can you add your UI Images?

Answer (score 2):

If your LNNumberpad is subclass of UIView, as i suppose, you can change it frame using auto layout, setting fixed width and height and set other constraints just like any other view.

[Apple reference to Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

Comment: I am using that as input view for UItextField

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your own keyboard or use the built-in Apple default (is there a good UX reason for this?) then you could set the frame your LNNumberpadView directly, or if you prefer, put inside a holderView, like so:

```
UIView * holderView = [UIView new];
holderView.frame = CGRectMake(w-100, h-200, 100, 200);
[self.view addSubview:holderView];
[holderView addSubview:LNNumberpadView];
```

where w = screen width and h = screen height.

Then manipulate your holderView to animate or whatever.